# PHP file download downloading wrong file

Tags: php, download, readfile

Hey peeps i need some help,

i was bored so i thought id toy around with youtube-dl a little.
I made a small web tool that just uses Youtube-DL for downloading and then downloads the file in the Browser. (this is the first time ive ever played around with downloading files so im sorry if this is a really basic noob thing)

Here is my Code:

```php
    if (isset($_POST['url'])) {
        if ($_POST['type'] == "Video") {

            shell_exec("youtube-dl " . $_POST['url']);
            $output = shell_exec("youtube-dl --get-filename " . $_POST['url']);

            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($output) . '"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($output));
            readfile($output);
        }

        die();
    }
```

But i encountered a really really weird problem. So Youtube-DL is working completely fine and downloads the Video correctly.

But the download part just downloads the php file itself (actually it just has the php file's name but is completely empty)

[image: php files downloading]

(also dont mind the weird name ive just put this in some other file but that shouldnt matter because i `die();` after doing my download stuff)

Maybe someone here can help me out! ^-^

Comment: sidenote passing unescaped user input to shell_exec is a really bad idea

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yeah yeah ik like i said this is just me toying around personally im not gonna make this public :P

Comment: Have you tried popen instead of shell_exec?

Comment: @AlexBarker i can try that but like i said Youtube-DL is working fine

Comment: @RedCube it's not so much about executing youtube-dl as it is about getting binary safe output from it.

Comment: @AlexBarker oh okay ill try it as soon as i can :P

Comment: @AlexBarker oof thank you so much for nudging me in the right direction! So i didnt end up using popen in the end because tbh i wasnt quite sure how it works. But i did some testing and even tho `shell_exec` shouldnt be async (and it probably isnt) but switching from `shell_exec` to `exec` did the trick! The download code was fine all along lol